# Как пропустить ошибку при парсинге, если нет заданного элемента?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Есть парсер сайта, название категории и подкатегорий берется из хлебных крошек, когда у категории нет подкатегорий, то возникает ошибка `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`, что логично
как пропускать эту ошибку, т.к. есть несколько категорий без подкатегорий?

ошибка возникает при попытке извлечения текста из category2

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import xlsxwriter

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

PAGES_COUNT = 1
OUT_FILENAME = 'out1.json'
OUT_XLSX_FILENAME = 'out.xlsx'


def dump_to_json(filename, data, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('ensure_ascii', False)
    kwargs.setdefault('indent', 1)

    with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, **kwargs)


def dump_to_xlsx(filename, data):
    if not len(data):
        return None

    with xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename) as workbook:
        ws = workbook.add_worksheet()
        bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

        headers = ['Название товара', 'Цена', 'Категория', 'Подкатегория', 'ПодПодкатегория']
        # headers.extend(data[0]['techs'].keys())

        for col, h in enumerate(headers):
            ws.write_string(0, col, h, cell_format=bold)

        for row, item in enumerate(data, start=1):
            ws.write_string(row, 0, item['name'])
            ws.write_string(row, 1, item['amount'])
            ws.write_string(row, 2, item['category'])
            ws.write_string(row, 3, item['category2'])
            ws.write_string(row, 4, item['category3'])
            # for prop_name, prop_value in item['techs'].items():
            #     col = headers.index(prop_name)
            #     ws.write_string(row, col, prop_value)


def get_soup(url, **kwargs):
    response = requests.get(url, **kwargs)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='html.parser')
    else:
        soup = None
    return soup


def crawl_products(pages_count):
    """
    Собирает со страниц с 1 по pages_count включительно ссылки на товары.
    :param pages_count:     номер последней страницы с товарами.
    :return:                список URL товаров.
    """
    urls = []
    fmt = 'https://autostol63.ru/granta/grantatun/?page={page}'

    for page_n in range(1, 1 + pages_count):
        print('page: {}'.format(page_n))

        page_url = fmt.format(page=page_n)
        soup = get_soup(page_url)
        if soup is None:
            break

        for tag in soup.select('div.caption > a'):
            href = tag.attrs['href']
            url = '{}'.format(href)
            urls.append(url)

    return urls



def parse_products(urls):
    """
    Парсинг полей:
        название, цена и таблица характеристик
    по каждому товару.
    :param urls:            список URL на карточки товаров.
    :return:                массив спарсенных данных по каждому из товаров.
    """
    data = []

    for url in urls:
        print('\tproduct: {}'.format(url))

        soup = get_soup(url)
        if soup is None:
            break

        name = soup.select_one('h1 > span').text.strip()
        amount = soup.select_one('span.autocalc-product-price').text.strip()
        category = soup.select_one('ul.breadcrumb > li:nth-child(2) > a > span').text.strip()
        category2 = soup.select_one('ul.breadcrumb > li:nth-child(3) > a > span').text.strip()
        category3 = soup.select_one('ul.breadcrumb > li:nth-child(4)').text.strip()


        # techs = {}
        # for row in soup.select('div.attribute > div'):
        #     cols = row.select('span')
        #     cols = [c.text.strip() for c in cols]
        #     techs[cols[0]] = cols[1]

        item = {
            'name': name,
            'amount': amount,
            'category': category,
            'category2': category2,
            'category3': category3,
        }

        data.append(item)

    return data


def main():
    urls = crawl_products(PAGES_COUNT)
    data = parse_products(urls)
    dump_to_json(OUT_FILENAME, data)
    dump_to_xlsx(OUT_XLSX_FILENAME, data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

к сожалению, пройтись по всему дереву, собирая url в массив, а потом просто по массиву через foreach, не хватает знаний.
Помогите, что нужно указать в коде, для пропуска данной ошибки?

Comment: Проверяйте на `None` и только потом берите `.text`, можете вынести эту проверку в отдельную функцию. Пусть функция возвращает пустую строку, если там `None`.

Comment: а как проверить? пытался через if x None, но все равно такая же ошибка. Как правильно проверить?

Comment: @Inside, лучше всего `if not x:` но можно и `if x is None:`

Comment: @gil9red if not category2:  pass после category2 все равно выдает тоже самое
наверняка делаю, что-то не то

Comment: @Inside, `select_one` вернет `None`, если не найден элемент, поэтому код `soup.select_one('ul.breadcrumb > li:nth-child(3) > a > span').text.strip()` в таком случае, по сути, будет `None.text.strip()`, поэтому проверку нужно делать для результата `select_one`, например `category2_el = soup.select_one('ul.breadcrumb > li:nth-child(3) > a > span')` + `category2  = category2_el.text.strip() if category2_el else ""`, но лучше в функцию вынести. Добавил ответ с этим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по комментарию, ошибка происходит в этой строке:

```
category2 = soup.select_one('ul.breadcrumb > li:nth-child(3) > a > span').text.strip()
```

Покажу вариант возврата пустой строки при отсутствии элемента.
Сделайте функцию:

```
def get_text(el) -> str:
    if not el:
        return ""

    return el.get_text(strip=True)
```

- В одну строку:

  ```
  def get_text(el) -> str:
      return el.get_text(strip=True) if el else ""
  ```

Используйте так:

```
category2 = get_text(soup.select_one('ul.breadcrumb > li:nth-child(3) > a > span'))
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: @Inside, пожалуйста :)